# Find pattern in line and replace where portion of pattern is evaluated in substitution

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text line (newick file format with bootstrap values) that contains many numbers between 0.000 and 1.000 that I want to multiply by 100 and return the value as a rounded integer between 0 and 100.  These numbers are all preceded by a ")" and followed by a ":".  There are other numbers in the line of text I want to leave untouched which aren't surrounded by these.  I've been trying to do this with a perl one-liner along the lines of:

```
perl -ape 's/\)(\d\.\d+):/\)int($1*100+.5):/eg' test.newick
```

However, it is failing because of a syntax error, I believe because it can't evaluate the `")"` and the `":"` I'm trying to keep in there in the replacement.  Any suggestions how I can do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Please post a sample text line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

- A parenthesis is a regex special character.  You just need to escape it with a backslash if you want it to be a literal in your LHS.
- Your RHS needs to use string concatenation, since it's being evaled
- Consider using `s{}{}` as your regex delimiter to avoid the leaning tower confusion

Resolves to the following:

```
perl -ape 's{\)(\d.\d+):}{")" . int($1*100+.5) . ":"}eg' test.newick
```

Alternatively, you could use lookahead and lookbehind assertions if you didn't want to have to duplicate the literal text in the RHS

```
perl -ape 's{\)\K(\d.\d+)(?=:)}{ int($1*100+.5) }eg' test.newick
```